# Button at bottom of Gridview (Android)

Tags: android, layout, button, gridview

There's a lot of similar questions, but most are written in unclear English or have incomplete solutions, so let me try to be precise about the behavior I want:

The user sees a GridView. If the items in the GridView are large enough that the user has to scroll to see more of the gridview, the user should see no button initially. When the user scrolls and reaches the bottom of the gridview, he should see a button which he can click on.

How can I get this in XML? The solutions I've tried so far end up either:

1) Overlaying the button on top of the gridview at the bottom of the viewport. The button is always visible.

2) Creating a "footer bar" in which the button appears. The button is always visible.

Neither of these are what I want since the button should not be visible until the user has scrolled to the bottom of the gridview.

(You could almost think of the gridview having an extra row at the bottom in which the button resides)

## Update 7/23:

Here's the current iteration. mButton.getMeasuredHeight() is 0 when it's called in onMeasure. Trying to set a width or height with setWidth() / setHeight() in init() doesn't change this. Where do I need to be setting a width / height for the button?

Note also that the app subsequently crashes soon after the grid loads. Not sure why.

```
public class MyGridView extends GridView {

  private Button mButton;

  public MyGridView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
  }

  public MyGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
  }

  public MyGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
  }

  private void init(Context context) {
    mButton = new Button(context);
    mButton.setText("test test test");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    int buttonLeft = left;
    int buttonTop = top + this.getMeasuredHeight();
    int buttonRight = left + mButton.getMeasuredWidth();
    int buttonBottom = bottom + getMeasuredHeight() + mButton.getMeasuredHeight();

    mButton.layout(buttonLeft, buttonTop, buttonRight, buttonBottom);
  }


  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, parentHeight + mButton.getMeasuredHeight());
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that you can do it with a `GridView`, but you could probably make it work with a `ListView`.

Comment: The short answer is you can't without modifying/extending GridView.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to extend the `GridView` and override the `layout` and `measure` methods.

```
void layout(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
  super.layout(...);
  /* layout your button here.. */
}
```

If this works then no need to override the `onMeasure` method, otherwise you have to add the the button height to `heightMeasureSpec` in `onMeasure`.

### Update:

Call  super.onMeasure first, then set measured dimensions.. this should work..

```
@Override protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{ 
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec); 

     int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) ; 
     int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec ); 
     this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth , 
                               parentHeight + mbutton.getmeasuredheight());

 }
```

### Update 2:

Do changes to init:

```
  private void init(Context context) {
    mButton = new Button(context);
    mButton.setLayoutParams(
                  new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 50));
    mButton.setText("test test test");
  }
```

and

```
int buttonBottom = bottom  + mButton.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Add the following method to your Gridview class.

```
public void addButton() {
    addView(mButton);
}
```

Call `addButton` just after setting the adapter to grid view.

Comment: Getting an error: "Scollview can host only one direct child”

Tried wrapping the GridView and Button in a linear layout and that didn't work. The gridview became unscrollable and the button was still at the bottom of the page, always visible.

Comment: I'm trying to give it a shot, but I don't actually know how to "layout my button." Could you be more specific?

Comment: I edited my original post with my custom view attempt. Can you take a look and tell me why I'm getting the null pointer exception?

Comment: NEVER put a GridView or ListView inside a ScrollView. Please. It will be terrible for performance and terrible for user experience.

Comment: You can even try adding the button from adapter... Add a dummy item to data list.. then in getview if its called for last position...create a button, set params, gravity and return it...

Comment: doesn't work:

07-31 14:43:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(26751): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView

Comment: You can try the suggestion in my last comment... Returning the button from getView method...